# How to reproduce this result from Wolfram Functions site?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Reading [this *Wolfram Functions* page](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/07/13/0001/) for hypergeometric $_2F_1$ function, I'm trying to reproduce this result with *Mathematica*. But not only doesn't it expand the function when appropriate assumptions are given, it doesn't even evaluate the statement to true (I took it from *Input Form* on the above linked page and replaced `/;` with `,`):

```
FullSimplify[Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, n, 1 + n, z] == 
  n!/(z^n Pochhammer[1/2, n])-((2 n Sqrt[1-z])/z) Sum[(Pochhammer[1-n, k] (1-1/z)^k)/
      Pochhammer[3/2, k], {k, 0, n - 1}], Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0]
```

> Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, n, 1 + n, z] + (
>     2 n Sqrt[1 - z] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 3/2, (-1 + z)/z])/z == (
>    z^-n n!)/Pochhammer[1/2, n]

At the same time, making a table of these `FullSimplify` statements with `n` varying from e.g. `0` to `10` I do get a list of `True`s.

This looks a bit strange, since I'd suppose all the knowledge base of *Wolfram Functions* should be built-in into *Mathematica*.

So, how to convince Mathematica that the statement is true in general? And ultimately, how to make it output such expansions directly (so that I could learn from it, not just check something I already know)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common trick is to use `DifferenceRootReduce[]` on the difference of the left and right-hand sides:

```
iden = Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, n, 1 + n, z] == n!/(z^n Pochhammer[1/2, n]) -
(2 n Sqrt[1 - z]/z) Sum[Pochhammer[1 - n, k] (1 - 1/z)^k/Pochhammer[3/2, k],
                        {k, 0, n - 1}];

DifferenceRootReduce[Subtract @@ iden, n]
   0
```

---

> This looks a bit strange, since I'd suppose all the knowledge base of MathWorld should be built-in into *Mathematica*.

— in Alpha, I would think so; *Mathematica*, not so much. `MathematicalFunctionData[]` gives a nice pile, but I've noticed that a fair number of the relations it has are not necessarily easily recognized by *Mathematica* to be true.

Comment: Hmm, it gives me `DifferenceRoot[...]` instead of `0` (MMA version 11.0). Do you have some `$Assumptions` defined?

Comment: A line break was accidentally inserted. Can you try again, please?

Comment: Yes, seems to work now.